# KeyError "RDS_DB_NAME" when trying to connect PostgresQL with Django with Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python, django, postgresql, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have deployed my Django app (Python 3.7) with AWS Elastic Beanstalk and are trying to connect it with a postgresQL database.

Following [AWS' tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html#python-django-update-app) I have three files in my .ebextensions folder:

**01_packages.config**

```
commands:
    01_postgres_activate:
        command: sudo amazon-linux-extras enable postgresql10
    02_postgres_install:
        command: sudo yum install -y postgresql-devel
    03_remove_cmake:
        command: "yum remove cmake"

packages:
    yum:
        git: []
        amazon-linux-extras: []
        libjpeg-turbo-devel: []
        cmake3: []
        gcc-c++: []
```

I need cmake3 and gcc-c++ for some python packages I'm running, and I'm removing cmake not to worry about a wrong version of cmake that seems to be installed by default.

**02_python.config**

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: mainapp.wsgi:application
    NumProcesses: 3
    NumThreads: 20
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: mainapp.settings
```

**db-migrate.config**

```
container_commands:
  01_migrate:
    command: "python manage.py migrate"
    leader_only: true
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: mainapp.settings
```

I've added a postgresQL DB through EB console. I've also tried first activating the virtual environment in the **db-migrate.config** file like this:

```
command: "source /var/app/venv/*/bin/activate && python manage.py migrate"
```

But no success.

The logs are telling me the 01_migrate command is returning an error. When I `eb ssh` into the EC2 instance, navigate to my app, activate the venv and then run `python manage.py migrate`, it gives me a KeyError that os.environ doesn't have a key named 'RDS_DB_NAME'. When I do `printenv` none of the environment variables show up either.

This is how the database part in my settings.py file look like:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': os.environ['RDS_DB_NAME'],
        'USER': os.environ['RDS_USERNAME'],
        'PASSWORD': os.environ['RDS_PASSWORD'],
        'HOST': os.environ['RDS_HOSTNAME'],
        'PORT': os.environ['RDS_PORT'],
    }
}
```

When I go to the console the health shows up as severe. I don't understand why these environment variables are not there after I connected the postgres database in the EB console.

Any ideas would be really appreciated? I've tried terminating and creating a new environment but no luck.

Comment: Since you are using Elastic Beanstalk, I don't think you need to install and activate a DB instance manually in the config file. Follow this guide https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-rds.html#python-rds-create and then redeploy your application, this should help

Comment: Thanks. I followed it and changed my 01 config file by deleting the 01 and 02 commands. I now still get a 502 bad gateway suggesting it didn't connect with the database? When I ssh into the instance and do `printenv` it still doesn't show any of the environment variables like RDS_DB_NAME like I would expect.

I'm also confused why it actually deploys suggesting it ran 01_migrate, but when I manually ssh and try the migrate I get the KeyError?

Comment: It's okay, if `printenv` shows nothing, because Elastic Beanstalk initializes environment variables automatically when deploying, that's why you cannot check them directly in the console. You need to download error logs of the application and check what went wrong

Comment: Oh goodness, I think I've just realized what is causing the error. In your `command: "source /var/app/venv/*/bin/activate && python manage.py migrate"` you must add `--no-input` after `migrate`. I had the same issue after deploying my EB instance on aws for the first time

Comment: Oh wow, it's crazy but that did it. It wasn't in the logs at all. Thanks so much, you're hero!

So there is no way to test the migrating through ssh to the ec2 instance?